# Bash - parsing ini file, finding section name by values within

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, ini

I have a config.ini file which looks like this (updated):

```
[group1]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=101
bookingnr=010100
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group2]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=102
bookingnr= 010101
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group3]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=103
bookingnr=010103
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group4]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=105
bookingnr=010105
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group5]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=106
bookingnr=010106
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group6]
base=100
hwadd=0x20
doorstatus=100
lock=107
bookingnr=010107
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group7]
base=100
hwadd=0x21
doorstatus=100
lock=101
bookingnr=010108
kode=1111
inuse=0

[group8]
base=100
hwadd=0x21
doorstatus=100
lock=102
bookingnr=010109
kode=1111
inuse=0
...
```

I need to get the room number where 3 given values (**base**, **hwadd**, **lock**) match the script parameters. So lets say the bash script was called like this:

```
script.sh 100 0x20 105
```

the script would return **4** (since all 3 parameters match group4)

Finding a single value is a piece of cake

```
source config.ini
```

and every value is available under **$valX** but this is not parsing the section names so it is useless in this case..

Comment: All three seem to match group2 as well.

Comment: Did you tried something? Show us!!

Comment: I had not seen comment from techno before and posted my solution, I had deleted it now; once you add your efforts in your question, will un-delete my answer then.

Comment: tbh. I have no idea how to start, I know regex, and how to find a string within ONE line but this is way beyond my skills.  My first approach was "source config.ini" but this is not parsing section names

Comment: @trojan it's always relatively trivial to write a script that will produce the expected output from a given sample input but **much** harder to not produce unexpected output for other input. When looking at answers here and deciding which "work" you have to really understand the code (ask questions if you don't) and/or have an input set that encompasses **all** of your edge/rainy-day cases. Just seeing that it produces the expected output from your posted sample input isn't nearly enough to tell if an answer "works" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
val='100 0x20 105'

awk -F= -v vals="$val" 'BEGIN {
   n = split(vals, w, /[ \t]+/)
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      values[w[i]] = 1
}
/^\[group[0-9]+]$/ {
   if (n == found)
      print grp
   delete seen
   found = 0
   grp = $0
   gsub(/^\[group|\]$/, "", grp)
}
NF == 2 && values[$2] && !seen[$2]++ {
   found++
}
END {
   if (n == found)
      print grp
}' file
```

```
4
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/j25nue)

Comment: I am getting error: on line 8 and 18: illegal reference to array r

Comment: I have included a working demo link with your updated data. Let me know if this works out or not.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your input data has name-value pairs it's best to first create an array (`f[]` below) that maps those names to their values and then at the end of every record you can simply compare the values by their names in whatever combination you like and print whatever values you like in whatever order you like just referencing them by their names.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *= *"; OFS="=" }
NF {
    if ( /]/ ) {
        gsub(/[^0-9]/,"")
        f["group"] = $0
    }
    else {
        f[$1] = $2
    }
    next
}
{ prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( (f["base"] == base) && (f["hwadd"] == hwadd) && (f["lock"] == lock) ) {
        print f["group"]
    }
    delete f
}

$ awk -v base=100 -v hwadd=0x20 -v lock=105 -f tst.awk file
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, it is in form of shell script which person needs to run by providing arguments to script(tested and written with shown samples).

```
cat script.ksh
val="$@"

awk -v arg="$val" '
BEGIN{
  FS="="
  num=split(arg,array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    array1[array[i]]
  }
}
/group/{
  if(sum==num){
    print group_value
  }
  sum=""
  gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"")
  group_value=$0
  next
}
($NF in array1){
  sum++
}
END{
  if(sum==num){
    print group_value
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

When I run it like:

```
./script.ksh xyz xyy zyx
3
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
cat script.ksh
val="$@"                         ##Creating a shell variable named val which has all values of arguments passed to script.
awk -v arg="$val" '              ##Starting an awk program from here and creating a variable arg whose value is shell variable val here.
BEGIN{                           ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS="="                         ##Setting FS as = here.
  num=split(arg,array," ")       ##Splitting arg variable into an array with delimiter as space here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){           ##Running for loop from i=1 to till value of num here.
    array1[array[i]]             ##Creating an array named array1 with index of value of array with index i here.
  }
}
/group/{                         ##Checking condition if line contains group string then do following.
  if(sum==num){                  ##Checking condition if sum==num then do following.
    print group_value            ##Printing variable group_value here.
  }
  sum=""                         ##Nullifying variable sum here.
  gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"")             ##Globally substituting everything apart from digits with NULL here in current line.
  group_value=$0                 ##Setting variable group_value value to current line value here.
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($NF in array1){                 ##Checking condition if last field of current line is present in array1 then do following.
  sum++                          ##Increase count of sum variable with 1 here.
}
END{                             ##Starting END block for this code here.
  if(sum==num){                  ##Checking condition if sum==num then do following.
    print group_value            ##Printing variable group_value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer! I am getting more than one section number when I test on live data, I have updated my question with real data.

Comment: @trojan, I tested this with your  first shown samples and it worked fine for me. I am not sure what you mean by "getting more than one section" could you please elaborate more on it

Comment: please se the updated example and try with the 100 0x21 102 as the input parameters - your script will return "2 8" but should only return 8

Answer (score 1):

Your script `script.sh` could be this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/^\[/p;/^base/p;/^hwadd/p;/^lock/p;d' config.ini |   # keep relevant lines
awk '
  BEGIN{RS = "["; FS = "\n"}
  {print $1, $2, $3, $4}
' |                                   # awk puts each block on one line
grep "base=$1 hwadd=$2 lock=$3" |     # filter line matching all records
sed -e 's/^group//' -e 's/\].*$//'    # extract group # from matching line
```

If you issue `./script.sh  100 0x20 105` with the **updated** `config.ini` file above, the output will be:

```
4
```

It is necessary that the entries `base=...`, `hwaddr=...` and `lock=...` always appear in this order in `config.ini` for a match. If this is not the case, please ask me to adapt the script.

Comment: You never need sed or grep when you're using awk.

Comment: Perhaps @Ed Morton is right but your code actually works!

Comment: @trojan code that produces the expected output for a given input set is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. Beyond that you have to consider everything that matters in software - clarity, performance, reliability, robustness, maintainability, ease of enhancement, etc., etc.

Comment: @EdMorton: why should I use **awk** with 15 lines of code instead of one **grep** and two **sed** in combination with 2 lines of **awk**? I prefer to use each tool for what it is designed. By the way, is the use of the function *gsub* in **awk** not a hidden call to what **sed** or **grep** is made for?

Comment: wrt `why` - because the result will be better for some combination of most of the things that matter in software - clarity, performance, reliability, robustness, maintainability, ease of enhancement, etc.. You don't need to write 15 lines of awk for this problem, you can solve it with a much briefer script, but brevity isn't a goal of software so if you don't focus on it then you get a better solution. wrt `gsub()` - that's like asking `is the use of sed and grep not a hidden call to what ed is made for?` and it has the same answer that its similar functionality and not hidden in the slightest

Comment: For example robustness - your script would fail for various input values, e.g. try changing `lock=107` in the posted sample input to `lock=1057` for the most likely example. Or add a line like `locker=105`. Or include RE metachars like `.` in the input names or target values. Now for example maintainability - try enhancing your script to also print `doorstatus` when the condition matches. Now enhance it to only print when the value of `base` is between `27` and `9253` and the value of `lock` is less than the value of `kode`. All absolutely trivial with the awk solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Sed variant

```
#!/bin/bash
val1=$1 # get value1
val2=$2 # get value2
val3=$3 # get value3
file="config.ini"   # ini file
raw=$(cat "$file")  # read file to this var
raw=${raw//$'\n'/ } # change new line to space
raw=${raw//[/'\n'}  # change [ to new line
# print through sed, sed prints number of group in matched string
printf "$raw" | sed -n "s/group\([0-9]*\).*$val1.*$val2.*$val3.*/\1/p"
```

Usage

```
$ ./test xyz xyy zyx
4
```

Comment: your script does not take into consideration other variables within the config file which may have the same value like the parameters

Answer (score 0):

[jc](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc) / [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) commands can be used for this:

I'm not sure whether you want the number to represent the order of the entry or the suffix of the entry's title so I provide both solutions:

```bash
# print-group-suffix.sh
# Print the title numeric suffix of the entry that matches the specific criteria
cat test.ini | jc -p --ini | \
        jq -r '. | with_entries(.key |= sub( "^group+"; ""))  | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.base=="'$1'" and .value.hwadd=="'$2'" and .value.lock=="'$3'") | .key'


# print-group-order.sh
# Print the order of enrty that matches the specific criteria
cat test.ini | jc -p --ini | \
        jq -r '. | map( if(.base=="'$1'" and .hwadd=="'$2'" and .lock=="'$3'") then "yes" else "no" end  ) | .[]' | grep -n "yes" | cut -d: -f1
```

Executing the above scripts:

```bash
print-group-suffix.sh 100 0x20 105
# 4

print-group-order.sh 100 0x20 105
# 4
```